# How to discretize nonlinear Poisson Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, optimization, numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to solve a nonlinear poisson equation of the form:

$u_{xx} + f(u_y)u_{yy} = 0$.

I would like to use Newton's method to handle the nonlinearity, however I am not sure when/how to discretize the differential terms.

If I identify $F[u]$ with the LHS of the above I could immediately write down (where n represents iterations):

$u^{n+1} = u^n - F'(u^n)^{-1}F[u]$

However, I am not sure how to proceed from here. I can write down a discretized version of $F$ but I do not know how to write down $F'^{-1}$.

Comment: You need a functional derivative. First you solve $\left. \frac{d}{d\epsilon}F(u^n+\epsilon \delta u) \right|_{\epsilon = 0} = - F(u^n)$ for $\delta u$ (this is a linear PDE for $\delta u$), and then you compute the update $u^{n+1} = u^n + \delta u$.

Comment: Hi @Christoph, thank you! As you can tell I am quite new to numerical methods. Do you have any references for learning/becoming more familiar with this material (a textbook would be ideal). The problem is that most of the texts I've seen only discuss finite differences for linear PDEs (e.g. Olver's Introduction to PDEs).

Comment: The ideas remain the same in the nonlinear case, p. ex. using $u_{ij} \simeq u(x_i,y_j)$ and central finite differences you could write \begin{eqnarray*}0 &=& u_{xx}(x_i,y_j) + f(u_y(x_i,y_j)) u_{yy}(x_i,y_j)\\&\simeq& \frac{u_{i+1,j} - 2 u_{ij} + u_{i-1,j}}{h^2} + f\left( \frac{u_{i,j+1} - u_{i,j-1}}{2h}\right) \frac{u_{i,j+1} - 2 u_{ij} + 2 u_{i,j-1}}{h^2},\end{eqnarray*} which (after also including the boundary conditions) yields a nonlinear system of algebraic equations for the unknowns $u_{ij}$, which can then be linearized. This is the opposite way of the approach suggested above.